# Adding or editing a child

Tags: swift, ios, api

I have a class which will add or edit a child. So whenever I click on "save," I need to check the child image. If it's an image, then I need to upload to the image server. Once that's done only, I need to save all other data to the data server. Here, I am looking for better names for methods `save()` and `updateChild()`.

```
 func saveAction() {
      switch validationResult {
      case .Success:
         save()
      case .Failure(let errorType):
         displayErrorAlert(errorType)
      }
 }

func save() {
    let child = addChildView.tableView.datasource
    if let image = child.image {
        uploadImage(image)
    } else {
        self.updateChild()
    }
}

func uploadImage(image: UIImage) {
    UploadManager.uploadImage(image, completion: { (response) in
        switch response {
        case .success:
            self.updateChild()
        case .error:
            self.updateChild()
        }
    })
}

func updateChild() {
    if addChildType == .new {
        addChild()
    } else {
        editChild()
    }
}
```

Comment: `if ... { addNewChild() } editChild()` or such.

Comment: Have you considered insert and update to data servers so that it relates to database languages